# openwrt parse the config

Tags: shell, openwrt

I am working on LuCI and want to change something on it. So the first thing I have to do is to figure out how it works. I know the LuCI configure files are parsed by the shell then the uci system use it as setting, but it is difficult to get the flow of the work. So I can't catch the point that I need. My question is:
Yeah, I found that there are some global variables shared.

1.How could I debug it to see trace the process in the openwrt?

2.The shell parses the config files in /etc/config/ for two use, one for LuCI interface, and the other for the driver setting. But How can I find the the one parse the wireless for hostapd.conf? It seems that the shell--functins.sh in /lib/ is related. But This is only a set of function---just tools. Where can the shell locate which call these functions?

Is there anyone who can help me? Any answer will be appreciated. I will very grateful.

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to achieve? Have you seen [this](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/luci.essentials) including the [technical reference](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/luci) and its further resources that it links to?

Comment: Actually, I want to divide the option channel into two,channel1 and channel2 in /etc/config/wireless. Because the 802.11a and 802.11na work in the different frequency as 802.11b/g/ng does. If the wrong frequency is chosen. The router will be down. But the original UI just mix all the frequency together. I just want to make a change in this. But I need the channel1 and channel2 parsed just the option channel. So I need figure out the parsing process of the configure file by the shell.Then I can make some change and make channel1 and channel2 parsed smoothly. Am I clear? Welcome to discuss it.

Answer (score 2):

The configurable parameters in the web interface:

- are first checked with LUA scripts in /usr/lib/lua/luci/...
- then they are passed to a shared library compiled from C and callable from LUA
- then written to /etc/config
- then when if you apply, the /sbin/wifi script will be called
- then it loads "functions.sh" to get shell support for UCI files
- then it calls "/lib/wifi/mac80211.sh" to parse the wifi network
  params depending on the network mode, mac80211.sh will call either
  "/lib/wifi/wpa_supplicant.sh" or "/lib/wifi/hostapd.sh" that finish
  the parsing, create the conf file and start the hostapd daemon.

I guess what you are looking for are /sbin/wifi, mac80211.sh and hostapd.sh.

If you want to debug, you can just put "echo" commands in these scripts, or use the shell "set -x" to trace them. You can invoque directly /sbin/wifi from the command line, it will restart the whole wifi and reparse the UCI files.

Comment: Yeah, the config files from Lua are parsed by the functions in the shell functions. Actually all the config file in the /etc/config/ is just shell, it is incredible ,isn't it? Then all the config parameters  will be passed as some environment variables. Then use the functions in the functions.sh get the wanted one.This is  the simple parsing process. But the wireless has more, whose config will be parsed by the shell in /lib/netifd/netifd-wireless hostapd.sh and wireless/mac80211.sh . The shell in /lib/wifi/mac80211.sh is used to initiate some arguments of wireless. Thank you for your answer.